# If statement with mysql_fetch_row in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to make this:

```
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE IP='$ip' LIMIT 1;")->fetchColumn();

    // mean this
    if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $delete = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM tables WHERE IP='$ip';");
    $delete->execute();
    }
```

in PHP Data Object (PDO)?

I tried that, but:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Comment: did you already try it by yourself? If so, could we see your approach and can you explain why it did not work? Please understand that the idea of stackoverflow is not that someone is doing your work for you.

Comment: Here's a good resource for you: http://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/  You should take a crack at it and report back if your solution isn't working.

Comment: Yup, aaand this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Topic edited. I saw that article on sitepoint, but still don't know how to do that.

Comment: you can't mix mysql and PDO. Use `$result->fetch()`

Comment: By use if ($result->fetch()) i got Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix different mysql extensions. If you use PDO to perform the query, you have to use PDO to fetch the results.

```
if ($result->fetch()) {
    ...
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use `->fetchColumn()` when you're setting `$result`.

You should also use a prepared query rather than substitute variables.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE ip = :ip");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $delete = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM tables WHERE ip = :ip");
    $delete->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
    $delete->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks to you I understand it :D

Comment: One more thing, how to store value from database into variable using PDO?

Comment: Okay, I find out method - PDO::FETCH_BOTH, it's working ;)